# Unable to connect WIA Scanner over virtual machine

Tags: vb.net, virtual-machine, wia

I have following vb code to connect scanner via WIA in a Windows form application.

```
Private Function Connect() As Device
    Dim WiaDev As Device = Nothing
    Dim manager As New DeviceManager()
    Try
        For Each info As DeviceInfo In manager.DeviceInfos
            If info.DeviceID = DeviceID Then
                WiaDev = info.Connect()
                Return WiaDev
            End If
        Next
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

It works fine in local. But in virtual machine it throws following exception while executing the line info.Connect(). Exception =>
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component". It will be nice if anybody suggest some solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that , it is necessary to install corresponding scanner driver in both local and virtual machine.